# State React и props. Теряется при export

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

Как правильно через пропс передать состояние?Подскажите плиз.Модал открывается, но не закрывается + я уверен что не так это прокидывается

```js
import React from "react";

import {MDBContainer, MDBRow, MDBCol, MDBMask, MDBBtn} from "mdbreact";

import Modal from "./Modal";
class Intro extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    state = {
        modal9: false
    };

    toggle = nr => () => {
        let modalNumber = "modal" + nr;
        this.setState({
            [modalNumber]: !this.state[modalNumber]
        });
    };


    render() {
        return (
            <header
                className="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center gradient header"
                id="main"
            >
                <MDBMask>
                    <MDBContainer>
                        <MDBRow>
                            <div className="white-text text-center text-md-left col-md-6 mt-xl-5 mb-5">
                                <h1 className="h1-responsive font-weight-bold mt-sm-5">
                                    Почему мы?
                                </h1>
                                <hr className="hr-light"/>
                                <h6 className="mb-4">
                                    Высокий профессиональный уровень специалистов. Врачи имеют
                                    большой опыт практической работы, систематически проходят
                                    курсы повышения квалификации в образовательных центрах мира,
                                    принимают участие в международных семинарах и конференциях.
                                </h6>
                                <MDBBtn color="white" onClick={this.toggle(9)}>
                                    Получи консультацию бесплатно
                                </MDBBtn>
                            </div>
                            <MDBCol md="6" xl="5" className="mt-xl-5"/>
                        </MDBRow>
                    </MDBContainer>
                </MDBMask>
                <Modal foo={this.state.modal9}/>
            </header>
        );
    }
}

export default Intro;

и сам модал

import {
    MDBBtn,
    MDBCol,
    MDBContainer,
    MDBIcon,
    MDBInput,
    MDBModal,
    MDBModalBody,
    MDBModalHeader,
    MDBRow
} from "mdbreact";
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";

export default class Modal extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            name: "",
            email: "",
            message: ""
        };
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange = e => {
        this.setState({[e.target.name]: e.target.value});
    };

    async handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        const {name, email, message} = this.state;

        const form = await axios.post("/api/form", {
            name,
            email,
            message
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <MDBModal isOpen={this.props.foo}  centered>
                <MDBModalHeader toggle={this.props.foo}>
                    Опишите вашу проблему ниже:
                </MDBModalHeader>
                <MDBModalBody>
                    <MDBContainer>
                        <MDBRow>
                            <MDBCol md="12">
                                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                                    <p className="h5 text-center mb-4">
                                        Мы всегда рады помочь вам
                                    </p>
                                    <div className="grey-text">
                                        <MDBInput
                                            className="senderName"
                                            label="Ваше имя"
                                            name="name"
                                            icon="user"
                                            group
                                            type="text"
                                            validate
                                            error="wrong"
                                            success="right"
                                            onChange={this.handleChange}
                                        />
                                        <MDBInput
                                            className="senderEmail"
                                            label="Ваш email"
                                            name="email"
                                            icon="envelope"
                                            group
                                            type="email"
                                            validate
                                            error="wrong"
                                            success="right"
                                            onChange={this.handleChange}
                                        />
                                        <MDBInput
                                            className="senderSubject"
                                            label="Тема"
                                            name="subject"
                                            icon="tag"
                                            group
                                            type="text"
                                            validate
                                            error="wrong"
                                            success="right"
                                            onChange={this.handleChange}
                                        />
                                        <MDBInput
                                            className="senderMessage"
                                            type="textarea"
                                            name="message"
                                            rows="2"
                                            label="Ваше сообщение"
                                            icon="pencil-alt"
                                            onChange={this.handleChange}
                                        />
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="text-center">
                                        <MDBBtn type="submit" outline color="secondary">
                                            Отправить{" "}
                                            <MDBIcon far icon="paper-plane" className="ml-1"/>
                                        </MDBBtn>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </MDBCol>
                        </MDBRow>
                    </MDBContainer>
                </MDBModalBody>
            </MDBModal>
        );
    }
}
```

[image: Открывает но не закрывает]

Comment: Вы почитайте ошибки на скрине, причем тут стейт? Вы функцию в пропсы не прокидываете

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в следующем вызове компонента:

```
<MDBModalHeader toggle={this.props.foo}>
  Опишите вашу проблему ниже:
</MDBModalHeader>
```

Вы передаете в `toggle` булево значение, а нужно передать функцию.
Чтобы решить проблему можно поступить следующим образом:

1) Изменить вызов `<Modal />`, добавив пропсу `onToggle` (в нее передаем фукнцию тогла).

```
<Modal foo={this.state.modal9} onToggle={this.toggle(9)} />
```

2) Новую пропсу передадим в `<MDBModalHeader />`

```
<MDBModalHeader toggle={this.props.onToggle}>
   Опишите вашу проблему ниже:
</MDBModalHeader>
```

Надеюсь, данное решение вам поможет!